# Adding a Vector2 to List

Tags: c#, xna

I have this code

```
    public List<Vector2> alienPosition = new List<Vector2>();

    for (int x = 0; x < alienPosition.Count; x++)
        {
            alienPosition[x].Add(new Vector2((x * 20) + 50, 20));
        }
```

and it gives me the error that Add doesnt take one argument. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to insert an item at a specific index, you use List<T>.Insert(index, T); Otherwise it's List<T>.Add(T);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public List<Vector2> alienPosition = new List<Vector2>();
    int someCount = 10;
        for (int x = 0; x < someCount; x++)
            {
                alienPosition.Add(new Vector2((x * 20) + 50, 20));
            }
```

Remove the [i] indexer and specify an end condition for the loop > 0

The [i] is needed for simple arrays. The list is a more high level data structure with convenience methods to add elements directly to the list. It's part of the list API to be able to add new entries without having to specify an index for the new entry. It will add new entries to the end of the list.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why that fixed it? I thought the indexer was needed to the for loop knows where to add the new Vector

Comment: Ok I get it. Now I'm having an issue where the for loop isnt actually adding anything to the list. When I place the code within the for loop outside of the loop it adds an alien though.

Comment: Ah I see the error. Your loop is running until alienPosition.Count which is 0 since the list is initially empty. You have to specify an end condition for the for loop > 0